# Iterating over a collection with an Activity for interacting with the properties of the objects

Tags: android, android-activity, iteration

How would I iterate over a collection with a different Activity to interact with each object within the collection?

For example if I have a survey collection (List maybe) full of question groups and questions, how would I have an Activity/layout for each question group and question given the fact that the questions within the collections are dynamically loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Activity.startActivityForResult(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start up the Intent and specify that you expect it to return something.  To exit the Intents, just call `finish()`.

Comment: Thanks. This will be enough to figure out the rest. You are the man.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your objective is, but you could put each question into a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), and use onItemClicked to launch the per-question activity when a user clicks on it.